# Difference between List form and InfoPath form?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Why and when we have to use InfoPath forms and when should we use List Forms?

Comment: Thanks Raja for your answer.can you please elaborate when we have to use infopath forms and when we have to use list form ?

Answer (score 0):

Info-Path forms are mostly designed and developed by SharePoint power user's and list forms are mostly developed by SharePoint Developers.

There are several other major differences between List and Info path forms, e.g. development possibilities, features available etc..